# Wrap Anchor Links and adjust Width of Div

Tags: html, css

I'm facing an issue with the sub-navigation menu on my website. The problem is that the `<a>` tag containing the text "Mathematik & Naturwissenschaften" doesn't resize properly when the browser window is small enough for the words to wrap. The desired appearance is without the "empty gray space".

[image: Desired Version with Wrapping]

```css
ul#subnavi a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 150%;
  background-color: #9c9e9f;
  clear: left;
}

ul#subnavi {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="subnavi">
  <li><a href="XYZ">Sprachen</a></li>
  <li><a href="XYZ">Gesellschaftswissenschaften</a></li>
  <li><a href="XYZ">Mathematik &amp; Naturwissenschaften</a></li>
  <li><a href="XYZ">künstlerisch-musische Fächer</a></li>
  <li><a href="XYZ">Religion</a></li>
  <li><a href="XYZ">Sport</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Go look up the `white-space` property.

Comment: use `white-space: nowrap` on a tags

Comment: This is normal behavior. Are you open to using JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Width / Max-Width on Line Wrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377826/css-width-max-width-on-line-wrap).

Comment: Javascript is fine, too. And no this is no dup...

Comment: How is it not? As far as I can tell, that's the same issue. There's an explanation of the behavior and a link to a JavaScript solution.

Comment: I correct me, I can't use Javascript... With pure CSS there is no solution?

Comment: Is there a way with `display: inline-block`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the line `white-space: nowrap;` to the CSS part. Here's a working sample https://jsfiddle.net/zkmpwry9/.

> The white-space property is used to describe how whitespace inside the element is handled.
>
> > nowrap
> >     Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text.

```
ul#subnavi a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 150%;
    background-color: #9c9e9f;
    clear: left;
    white-space: nowrap; /* the extra line */
}
```

Comment: I want, that the text to wrap, but I don't want the space on the right, if it wraps... And white-space: nowrap; doesn't solve my problem, it only prohibits the wrapping, this is not my aim...

Answer (score 0):

Use white-space: nowrap; this help to not colapse!

Comment: mm okey, so try this ->  "overflow:hidden;"