# Extra spacing after element when using max-width w/ background

Tags: css

The title of the post most likely isn't sufficient. Please edit and/or comment if another suits my question better.

**Question:**

Why is there extra space after the 2nd word on the first line? I would like it to be flush (padding applied).

[image]

- I'm using bootsrap v3.3. I have a hero image (used as background),
  followed by a `.container`, then a wrapper element that is absolute
  positioned (solely vertical at first).
- Inside the wrapper element there is an `h1`.
- The `#heroBox` has the background applied.
- I've tried to move the styles for padding, background-color, etc to
  the `h1` instead of the `#heroBox`, but still get the same effect.
- I have tried adding `width:auto` to the `#heroBox`, along w/ other styles
- There is `letter-spacing: -1px;` on the `h1`, but removing it does nothing.

---

```
<div id="mainHero" style="background-image:url(someURL);">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="heroBox" class="">
            <h1>Telehealth Through Teladoc</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    #heroBox {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%; 
        left: 0;
        width: auto; // doesn't work
        max-width: 35%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        color: $color-text-offwhite;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
        background-color: #000;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        padding: 10px 30px; // it is not the padding

        h1 {
            margin: 0;
            text-transform: none;
            font-size: 2.5rem; 
            // display: inline; // doesn't work
            // word-wrap: break-work; // doesn't work
        }
    }

    .container {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 100;
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? I tried creating one, but I'm unable to simulate the layout close to what you have in the screenshot.

Comment: How would you like the text to look? As wrapping is expected just like your screenshot.

Comment: You can go here - http://www.directmedaccess.com/our-benefits/dental/  --- remove `left` from `#heroBox` and add `max-width:34%` on it

Comment: @Pangloss I would like it to be flush (including padding). There is too much space on the right side

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12377883/483779