# Is it possible to shrinkwrap flex items with wrapping text inside them?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering, display

I have an unassuming nav menu:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/real-estate"><span>Real Estate &amp;&nbsp;Development</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/new-business"><span>New &amp; Expanding Business</span></a></li>
        { … }
    </ul>
</div>
```

This menu needs the following visual properties:

- Items distributed horizontally within their container by putting equal space between them
- Text in items can wrap to make items take up less horizontal space
- All text is vertically centered.

I can't get all three of these at the same time.

This SCSS:

```
div > ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    > li {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        word-wrap: break-word;

        > a {
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    }
}
```

…gets me great spacing with vertical centering, but the text doesn't wrap, so the items overflow the container:

[image: Overflowy flex nav]

If I delete the `display: table` stuff:

```
div > ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    > li {
        // DELETED display: table;
        // DELETED table-layout: fixed;
        word-wrap: break-word;

        > a {
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    }
}
```

…then I get good text wrapping, but the spacing between the items is all off:

[image: Janky-spaced flex nav]

I've tried lots of other combinations of CSS properties, but nothing has gotten me any closer than these two. [Here's a pen with my code.](https://codepen.io/75th/pen/eVQqQb?editors=0100) Is there any incantation that will get me all the things I want from this menu?

**EDIT**: My Pen now includes a third attempt that uses another Flex container instead of display: table-cell. The spacing is better, but still not great. I guess this may just come down to the text-wrapping width issue described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12377883), and I may just have to hard code some line breaks or use JavaScript.

**EDIT 2**: The thing about that, though, is that the items aren't maxing out at a set size. On my third attempt there, the ones that wrap and end up bigger than the width of the wrapped text do *not* end up the same size as each other. And in fact the `space-between` isn't doing much of anything, because the top-level flex items are filling the entire space; the space-between them is 0px.

Comment: In the last example, it looks like the spacing between is fine. Do you mean you want each item to have an equal width? i.e. _"Real Estate & Development"_ is the same width as _"Global"_?

Comment: The spacing between them is not equal at all. Look at the difference between the left-edge-to-first-item spacing and the last-item-to-right-edge. Look at the gap between the first two items compared to the gap between Global and Career Center.

Comment: So that's a "no" on the equal width question? Why do you need `display: table`?

Comment: `display: table` makes the spacing nice and even, but doesn't allow wrapping. Removing it allows wrapping, but makes the spacing janky. And yeah, I don't want them the same width necessarily, I want them spaced evenly, as `justify-content: space-between` is supposed to do. But see my edit to my question for why I may be on a wild goose chase.

Comment: Yep, that edit post looks like your issue. Even though you're not setting a max-width, the text doesn't re-size after wrapping.

Comment: The thing about that though is that the menu items aren't maxing out at a set size. Several of the items end up wider than their post-text-wrap width, but they're not the same size. Maybe it's proportional based on how long the text was before wrapping?

Comment: Ya, something along those lines. Kind of like it will go on for x-length before wrapping and then stays at that size.

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex` instead of `table-cell` on the `a` elements, and then **put `width: min-content` on the `span`s inside them**:

```
div > ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    > li > a {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;

        span {
            width: min-content;
        }
    }
}
```

You might get more text wrapping than you bargained for this way, but you can control that with non-breaking spaces.

Comment: The min-content works perfectly, but as you mentioned there is more additional text-wrapping than required. I have the same scenario, however the non-breaking spaces is not an option due to the content being pulled in from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Text should already wrap automatically inside flex items.  It is working for me with the following code:

SCSS:

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  li {
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/real-estate"><span>Real Estate &amp;&nbsp;Development</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/new-business"><span>New &amp; Expanding Business</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/new-business"><span>New &amp; Expanding Business</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/974sbzpx/4/)

You can adjust spacing between items with `justify-content`:

```
.container {
  justify-content: flex-start | flex-end | center | space-between | space-around | space-evenly;
}
```

[cssTricks page for Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

You can make items take equal width by setting `flex-basis: 0; flex-grow: 1;` on the `li` elements.

Comment: Your fiddle didn't have enough different sizes of nav items to see the uneven spacing. [Here's a fork that does.](https://jsfiddle.net/tqnevahj/1/)

Comment: Just updated.  I think adding `flex-basis: 0; flex-grow: 1;` to your `li` elements should fix the issue with spacing.

Comment: That didn't have good results on my actual website or [in my pen (Attempt Five)](https://codepen.io/75th/pen/eVQqQb?editors=1100), unfortunately.

Comment: @75thTrombone Try taking `display: table` off of `li`