# content inside div has bigger width as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some text inside a div.
The parent of the div that holds the text has a specific width and `display: flex;`
I want the width of the container that holds the text to be as wide as its longest textline (in the fiddle this would be the line "WordyWords in").

I know this can be done by: `display: inline`, but this only works, when the parent does not have `display: flex` anymore.

```css
.width{
width: 150px;
display: flex;
}

.text{
 font-size: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
display: inline;
background-color: red;
}

.width2{
width: 150px;
}

.text2{
 font-size: 20px;
line-height: 20px;
display: inline;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
This is what I have 

<div class="width">
<div class="text">Veryvery long WordyWords in here</div>
</div>



<br>


 This is kind of what I want, but I want to keep the <span style="background-color: #f2f2f2">display: flex;</span> attribute in the parent
<div class="width2">
<div class="text2">Veryvery long WordyWords in here</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Like shown in the picture, I would like the div `.text` to end right after the letter of the longest textline like `display: inline` does this. (The red line is where the `.text` div should end.) **But I want to keep `display: flex` property on my parent.**  Is this even possible with flex set on the parent?

Comment: No...it's not -

Comment: I think my picutre was misleading a bit, I removed It.

Comment: I don't seem to understand why `display: inline` is just working fine. Its exactly what I want, but apparently setting `display: flex`on the parent breaks this. Why is that?

Comment: This is the normal behaviour. Read this answer and you will understand https://stackoverflow.com/a/12377883/7982963.

Comment: @Paulie_D Sooooo.... I found a "solution" to this problem. (needs some adjustment depending on personal application). But solving my question WAS possible ;) Would you mind unflag my question, so I can answer it myself, or would it be better to answer on the questions you suggested me?