# Get rid of empty space on the right when word-wrap happens

Tags: html, css

Below is simple example illustrating the problem. I have "Stackoverflow Stackoverflow" string and in first case it is displayed as a single line and in the second case word wrap happens. As you can see in the second case width of the div element is wider than a single "Stackoverflow" word. Is there a way to get rid of this empty space on the right? Resulting element has width 200px as specified per max-width but I want element to have actual width which is enough to fit it into 200px after word wrap.

```css
body {
    font-size: 30px;
}
      
.row {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
        
.text-no-wrap {
    background: yellowgreen;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}

.text-wrap {
    max-width: 200px;
    background: tomato;
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-no-wrap">Stackoverflow Stackoverflow</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-wrap">Stackoverflow Stackoverflow</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is because parent element row is flex box and its child will take 100% of full width of parent element. It is not about your overflow-wrap issue.

Comment: @LwinHtooKo This is not true, flexbox does not stretch children by default. Beside you can see in the example that elements have their own size and are not stretched.

Comment: you are right. it is nothing to do with flex box. My apologies. As the nature of a block, it will try to get as much space as possible.  It seems impossible to me. It totally depends on the width you set. You can also check "work-break: break-all".

Comment: Looks like this question is closed, but if you know how wide the browser is before it wraps, you can "hack" it by wrapping the second "Stackoverflow" with a span.

Then use a media query at the right browser width to set `display:block` to the span. This will mean the elements are no longer wrapping so the whitespace is gone.

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding `width: max-content;` to the div's insde the `.row`

Note that `width: max-content`; isn't supported in Internet Explorer, but is supported on all other browsers.

[Check the support of width: max-content; here.](https://caniuse.com/?search=max-content)

I've added `flex-direction: column;` to the .row so the children of those
div's will appear underneath each other.

If you need `display: flex;` on the `.row` div, then This is the way to go. If you don't need `display: flex;` on the `.row` div, just simply remove it. And only use `width: max-content;` on the children;

```css
body {
    font-size: 30px;
}
      
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
        
.text-no-wrap {
    width: max-content;
    background: yellowgreen;
}

.text-wrap {
    width: max-content;
    background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-no-wrap">Stackoverflow1 Stackoverflow2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-wrap">Stackoverflow1 Stackoverflow2</div>
    <div class="text-wrap">Stackoverflow1 Stackoverflow2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example there is no word wrapping. You display things in single line. I have added two elements at the bottom just to make it more apparent that two word wrapped items are longer than a single line item.

Comment: You've also added max-width to those div's. It seems that display: flex; makes those div's get the full width of the max-width you've set.

Comment: I have removed flexbox completely and edited my question to be more specific.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this one is not a text-wrap issue. If you check the following code you will get multiple spaces in between wrapping text. This one is due to the

> max-width: 200px;

specified for

> .text-wrap.

```css
body {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
          
    .row {
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
            
    .text-no-wrap {
        background: yellowgreen;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .text-wrap {
        max-width: 200px;
        background: tomato;
        white-space: normal;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<body>

<div class="row">
    <div class="text-no-wrap">Stackoverflow Stackoverflow</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-wrap">Stackoverflow Stackoverflow testing text wrapping space issue</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Go through the demo you can see that after "testing text" multiple spaces is there.

Comment: This is exactly an issue with word wrap and max-width. As you pointed out resulted element width is max-width but really less space is required than 200px, so I want element to have this minimum space required to show it rather than specified max width.

Comment: Then why the multiple space after the "testing text" while running the above code. Please explain. @Aleksey

Comment: @Aleksey are you able to identify the above-specified issue of multiple spaces after the "testing text"?

Comment: It is default behaviour. It basically sets with to max-width when word-wrap happens. To avoid this need to set `width: min-content;` and then width would be set to the width of the longest text line instead of `max-width`

Comment: so the extra space after "stackoverflow" is also the default behavior. right? @Aleksey

Comment: Yes. I found my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377826/css-width-max-width-on-line-wrap

Comment: So that's not a text wrap issue. That was my intention to the answer specified. @Aleksey