# CSS inline or inline-block type element bounding box stretched where word breaks

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Does anyone know why the bounding box is in CSS inline-block (or inline) element is not ended like in the first cell? I have made this picture to demonstrate what I want:

[image]

Somehow when `<h3>` title is break into two lines, the bounding box goes trough 100% with of the column. The `<h3>` and `<p>` elements are contained in a `display="flex"` element with following CSS attributes:

```
.cell {
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-start;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

Here are some additional pictures to demonstrate rendering:

[image]
[image]

```css
.css-15symnw {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));
  width: '200%';
}

.css-1yejq71 h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background: #222;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-15symnw">
  <div class="chakra-stack css-1yejq71">
    <h3>USB/EtherCAT Interface</h3>
    <p>SIRIUS DAQ system can be connected via USB or EtherCAT to any Windows-compatible PC or to one of our high-performance SBOX data loggers.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chakra-stack css-1yejq71">
    <h3>Any Sensor</h3>
    <p>Array of different amplifiers are available that can acquire data from virtually any sensor on the market. IEPE, voltage, high voltage, charge, full/half/quarter bridge, LVDT, RTD, thermocouples, current, resistance, counter, encoder, and digital
      inputs are available.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chakra-stack css-1yejq71">
    <h3>Universal Analog Inputs</h3>
    <p>Universal analog inputs are available that&nbsp;can accept voltage and&nbsp;full/half/quarter bridge signals natively&nbsp;as well as IEPE, charge, thermocouples, RTD, current, resistance, and LVDT&nbsp;signals with the use of&nbsp;DSI adapters.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chakra-stack css-1yejq71">
    <h3>160 dB Dynamic Range</h3>
    <p>Our DualCoreADC®&nbsp;technology boosts dual 24-bit delta-sigma ADC's&nbsp;with an anti-aliasing filter on each analog channel, achieving an astonishing 160 dB dynamic range in time and frequency domain with 200 kHz sampling rate per channel.&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chakra-stack css-1yejq71">
    <h3>1 MHz Sampling Rate</h3>
    <p><strong>A combination</strong>&nbsp;of software and hardware allows for acquisition speeds up to 1 MHz per channel on SIRIUS HS devices&nbsp;with real-time data processing and streaming to disk.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chakra-stack css-1yejq71">
    <h3>High Galvanic Isolation</h3>
    <p>High channel-to-channel and channel-to-ground isolation prevents damage to the systems from excessive voltage and avoids ground loops.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chakra-stack css-1yejq71">
    <h3>Flexible and Scalable</h3>
    <p>SIRIUS DAQ system&nbsp;can grow with your needs. You can start with a&nbsp;single channel and scale the system to thousands of channels at any time.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chakra-stack css-1yejq71">
    <h3>Sensor Power Supply</h3>
    <p>Amplifiers provide&nbsp;channel-independent, programmable power supply for sensor excitation.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chakra-stack css-1yejq71">
    <h3>Digital/Counter/Encoder Inputs</h3>
    <p>Each channel is capable of 3x digital inputs, 1x event counter, encoder, period, pulse-width,&nbsp;duty-cycle, and&nbsp;precise frequency and angle measurement using&nbsp;patented SuperCounter®&nbsp;technology.&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chakra-stack css-1yejq71">
    <h3>Isolated CAN and CAN FD Input</h3>
    <p>High-speed CAN FD and CAN 2.0b interface&nbsp;with 1 Mbit/sec data throughput with additional support for CCP, OBDII, J1939, and CAN output.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chakra-stack css-1yejq71">
    <h3>Analog Outputs/Function Generator</h3>
    <p>SIRIUS slice can be configured with 8 analog outputs which can also function as a multi-channel function generator (software option upgrade required), analog replay, or control device with the output voltage signal of ±10V.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chakra-stack css-1yejq71">
    <h3>Fully Synchronized</h3>
    <p>Each channel, analog,&nbsp;digital, or CAN is synchronized with microsecond accuracy.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chakra-stack css-1yejq71">
    <h3>Software Included With Free Lifetime Upgrades</h3>
    <p>Easy-to-use but rich in functionality, award-winning data acquisition software - DewesoftX is included. All software upgrades are free forever with no hidden licensing or maintenance costs.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/vfx24mbk/

Comment: Please add an [example].

Comment: @Kameron here https://jsfiddle.net/dazr06fL/

Comment: @PrimozRome check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/2weortdb/3/). With your structure, you will have to use js as denoted in the answer tagged as duplicate.

Comment: @Kameron uff yes thank you, but I do not want to use javascript to solve this. There must be CSS-only solution to this?

Comment: @PrimozRome I would think there would be too. But as mentioned in the duplicate answer js seems to be the only option **(however, that was 7 yrs ago)**. Read [BoltClock's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377826/css-width-max-width-on-line-wrap/12377883#12377883) on this, it was helpful for me. I will vote to reopen to see if we can get some potential modern solutions.

Comment: @Kameron there is no modern solution, that's how CSS is supposed to work and will always work that way even for the next 7 years

Comment: @TemaniAfif Your knowledge is always appreciated.