# In CSS, how can I prevent a gap to the right when multi-line text is constrained inside a wrapper?

Tags: html, css, width, word-wrap

**EDIT:** It turns out this is currently impossible with just CSS. A good explanation can be found here: [CSS Width / Max-Width on Line Wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377826/css-width-max-width-on-line-wrap/12377883#12377883)

---

Below, I have an `outer` class which specifies a fixed width, and an `inner` class which contains text.

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.inner {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.outer {
  width: 12.5rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
```

This leaves a gap to the right of the text:

**A:** [image]

But I would like the `inner` class to wrap tightly to the text itself, like this:

**B:** [image]

How can I achieve **B** using CSS?

I need a solution that is more dynamic than specifying an exact width for `inner` and doesn't change where the line breaks occur (e.g. using  `word-wrap: break-all`)!

---

**Clarification**

The padding is there just to help make the example look clearer. Without padding, the issue remains.

I get:

[image]

But I would like:

[image]

Comment: In your `.outer` container you have the same padding at all sides. Why don't you use a bigger padding to the right?

Comment: That would create extra space between the blue and grey borders, but without making the grey border tightly wrap the text.

Comment: This is because you have `padding` to the right in the `inner` container. So try to put `padding-right: 0.5rem` to `outer` and `padding-right: 0` to `inner`.

Comment: I have added some clarification about padding to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .inner {
  padding: 0.25rem 0 0.25rem 0.25rem;
border: 1px solid grey;
word-break: break-all;
}

.outer {
  width: 12.5rem;
padding: 0.25rem 1.5rem 0.25rem 0.25rem;
border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is closer to what I'm aiming for, but I'm looking for a solution which doesn't change where the line breaks occur.