# How to dynamically increase the container height based on the content inside it?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this React component where I want my `.lower-display` to grow vertically as per the content entered by the user -

```
const Display = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="display bg-dark">
            <div className="upper-display">{props.sample}</div>
            <div className="lower-display" id="display">{props.display}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I have the following styles to applied to each of the `div` elements -

```
.display{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.upper-display{
    min-height: 30px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: orange;
}

.lower-display{
    min-height: 35px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

This doesn't give the results as expected. The content inside the `.lower-display` starts overflowing horizontally.

I tried using `word-wrap: break-word;` property, but it doesn't work either. How do I fix it?

Comment: Use p tags instead of divs?

Comment: Set a width for `.lower-display`... this would force the container to grow with the text

Comment: @Wimanicesir I tried putting them in p tags and it didn't work. Also used fixed width as mentioned by the other person and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove the `flex` css from `.lower-display` class and add the following css:**

```
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100%;
```

Here.

- `max-width:100%` prevents the width value of your `.lower-display` css from becoming larger than the full width (100%).
- `width: fit-content` make use of the available space of the div
- I removed `display: flex` and added `display: inline-block` for making sure the above two properties are applied to the div since `flex` was preventing the content wrap.
  This would wrap your `.lower-display` to grow vertically as per the content entered by the user. Notice I added `color: black` here (for better view).

Bellow is full CSS for your problem:

```
.display {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.upper-display {
  min-height: 30px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: orange;
}

.lower-display {
  min-height: 35px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

**[Check the react Sandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-dew-dxzmc9)**

References:

1. [MDN Docs: width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)
2. [MDN Docs: max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)
3. [Stackoverflow comment that helped me find this Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377826/css-width-max-width-on-line-wrap#comment85971259_46705023)

Comment: Just had to add the `word-wrap: break-word` and it works. Thanks!!