# Shrink flex box when text inside multiline

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When text in the left block is wrapped to multiline (second row), the left block is stretched to maximum width and the right block is aligned to the right.

How can I make the left block shrink to the minimum width and right block immediately follow after text ("very2" word in example), like in the first row?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/realevd/9kyc182v/15/)

```html
<style>
.container {
  background: lightgray;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.left {
  background: lightyellow;
}

.right {
  background: lightskyblue;
}
</style>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      Left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      Very very long text very very2 longtexttexttext very 
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Width / Max-Width on Line Wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377826/css-width-max-width-on-line-wrap). There is not a way to fix it with CSS, unfortunately, but there si a JavaScript solution there.

Comment: The problem is similar. It’s bad that no CSS-only solution in 10 years

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are asking for.

```
.container {
  background: lightgray;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  
}

.left {
  background: lightyellow;
  width: min-content;
}

.right {
  background: lightskyblue;
}
```

Comment: I'm tried this and much more. Text in left block now has 4 lines, but I need text with minumum lines and max width without huge space on right

Comment: I see, did not realize you wanted a max of two lines. Ya, without JS I wouldn't know.