# How to resize the width of a div to fit word wrap?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to resize a `div` element when word wrap occurs? For demonstration purposes, look at this example from a similar question:

```css
.mypost {
  border: 1px solid Peru;
  margin: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}

.test {
  margin: 10px;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="mypost">
  <div class="test">I represent the imagdfv fdvdsdfsdfve.</div>
</div>
```

If you make the window smaller so that word wrap occurs, you will see that there is a blue empty space to the right of the text. Instead, I want the blue area to decrease until it reaches the last letter of the first line.

[image: word wrapped text in a element with a blue background with empty space]

(In this image I am forcing word wrap. I want the blue area to shrink.)

Is this possible?

Comment: `word-break: break-all;` is ok for your case, or you searching for more elegant way? http://jsfiddle.net/95d1fe54/1/

Comment: Im not after that effect, i still want the word break (the whole word). So the blue area should be dynamic in its width.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible. Let's wait more experienced coders

Comment: It's not possible

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377826/css-width-max-width-on-line-wrap) might help.

Answer (score 3):

By default div elements are [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) meaning they occupy 100% of the width of its parent element. As the other answer shows you can use javascript to set the width of the div according to the content.

However, if you are only concerned with constraining the background color to be within the boundaries of inline content (i.e. text and images), you could just make the element inline with the `display: inline` declaration. You would have to remove the margin and instead add padding to the parent element.

Here is an example I created from modifying your code. I added `display: inline` to `.test`, removed `margin: 10` from `.test`, and added `padding: 10` to `.mypost`. I also had to play around with `line-height` and `font-size` to make sure there is no gap between the lines.

```css
.mypost {
    border: 1px solid Peru;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 200px;
    width:300px;
    display: inline-block;

    background: red;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:20px;
    
    padding:10px;
    
}
.test {
    background: cyan;
    display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="mypost">
    <div class="test" contenteditable="true">
        EDIT ME..... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    </div>
</div>
```

The snippet is an interactive demo. You can directly edit the content of the div to see how word wrap behaves.

I have also found this duplicate question but it didn't have any satisfactory answers: [How to remove extra space caused by word-wrap in shrunk to fit element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110847/how-to-remove-extra-space-caused-by-word-wrap-in-shrunk-to-fit-element)

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr: No.

Once word wrapping occurs, the block-level element containing the text is considered to be as wide as possible to fill its container regardless of where the text breaks.

One can use javascript to find a minimum-width box of the starting height but this is inefficient due to repeated redraws and it's less friendly to CSS:

```js
target = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];
height = target.clientHeight;
minWidth = 1;
maxWidth = target.clientWidth;
while(maxWidth - minWidth > 1) {
  var newWidth = (minWidth + maxWidth) / 2;
  target.style.width = newWidth + "px";
  if(target.clientHeight > height) {
    minWidth = newWidth;
  }
  else {
    maxWidth = newWidth;
  }
}
target.style.width = maxWidth + "px";
```

```css
.mypost {
    border: 1px solid Peru;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
}
.test {
    margin: 10px;
    background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="mypost">
    <div class="test">I represent the imagdfv fdvdsdfsdfve.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

For me, I would make the inner div `display: inline-block;`

So:

```css
    .mypost {
        border: 1px solid Peru;
        margin: auto;
        min-width: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        background: red;
    }
    .test {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px;
        background: cyan;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="mypost">
        <div class="test">I represent the imagdfv<br/>fdvdsdfsdfve.</div>
    </div>
```