# Inherit multi-line inline child's width

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make a div that will inherit its child width.

It works when child has only one line, but when it becomes multiline, the parent gets width of max-width property.

HTML:

```
<div class="message-content">
    <span>Lorem ipsumdolor ipsum dolorsit ametipsumdolor ipsum dolor sit amet ipsumdolor ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.message-content {
    max-width: 450px;
    background: green;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    span {
       background:red;
    }
}
```

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/q0axyfp3/

Expected result:
[image]

**EDIT**
Here's the comparison of what I'm trying to achieve (in a responsive and elegant way of course):
https://jsfiddle.net/q0axyfp3/5/

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you very much

Comment: Your "CSS" is Less or SCSS; not actually CSS.

Comment: Actually I don't get what it is you want. To me it seems you're already there.

Comment: This is a little confusing.Do you want `message-content` to be the same width as `span`?

Comment: @MattSpinks Exactly (excluding padding)

Comment: _Inherit_ from a child? If I understood you correctly, you just need `display: block` in the `span`. Also that nesting in CSS is not valid.

Comment: @Gabriel CSS was a typo, fixed. But if I change span to be block element, then it'll behave exactly as parent div and gets more width than it's needed. Please compare expected result to JSfiddle's.

Comment: @squidy06 - Still a little confusing. `span` does not have a width. How do you want the parent div to be the same width of something that does not have a width? Why not just set a width on `span` and set the display to `block`?

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to achieve (in a responsive way of course):
https://jsfiddle.net/q0axyfp3/5/

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly... **you can't** that's not the way the line box model works.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width

Comment: possible duplicate: [**Make container shrink-to-fit child elements as they wrap**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37406353/3597276)

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize the width of a div if a word wrap happened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643678/how-to-resize-the-width-of-a-div-if-a-word-wrap-happened)

Answer (score 0):

Give it a wrapper element written in html.  Then set the width of both div's at 100%.  Set the wrapper element to have a max-width of whatever you like.

Comment: This won't change wrappers width to minimum possible

Comment: hmm.  you could try using a css table attributes. @squidy06

Comment: Could you please adapt your idea to this fiddle?
https://jsfiddle.net/q0axyfp3/5/

Comment: Now I see what your getting at.  I'm stumped.